# Bootstrap popover doesn't allow file upload until HTML updated

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I'm using bootstrap popover all over a site and it's working fine. I have one particular form that has a bunch of elements that work fine until the file upload. I have a drag and drop area for it and a button to bring up a file dialog box (it opens but doesn't place the file). Neither of these functions work. I've played around with the z-index and other minor things with no change.

I then realised after more testing that if I update the DOM by replacing the HTML of anything, even with itself it then makes it work. At the moment I'm replacing the submit button with itself and both the dialog box and the drop file area start working as expected again. I've retrofitted events onto the display of the popover to add useless html into the popover which will fix the issue however this seems very hacky.

Can anyone shed some light on this issue or a less hacky way to fix it?

Comment: Hard to answer without concrete code, I've never had this issue before personally.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yeah I know :/ There is a lot of code behind it so not something I could post on this site. Was more curious of others that had come across it or could shed some light on what could be the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Hi ive had the same thing. Its not verry hacky its just little buggs. When I had projects on my older computer I had the same problem it just would not auto update untill I made the slightest change in the file then the DOM would update.

Now on my new computer it does it automatically. So my best guess would to be its just a little bug.